# Why does the Borrow trait require the borrowed type to be a reference?

Tags: reference, rust, traits

Imagine some event source, which produces events represented as an enum. Of course, for best efficiency, this producer is zero-copy, i.e. it returns references to its internal buffers:

```rust
enum Variant<'a> {
    Nothing,
    SomeInt(u64),
    SomeBytes(&'a [u8])
}

impl Producer {
    fn next(&'a mut self) -> Variant<'a> { ... }
}
```

This is perfectly fine for consumers that don't require lookahead or backtracking, but sometimes there is a need to save some sequence of events. Thus, our `Variant` type becomes a generic:

```rust
enum Variant<BytesT> {
    Nothing,
    SomeInt(u64),
    SomeBytes(BytesT)
}

type OwnedVariant = Variant<Vec<u8>>;
type BorrowedVariant<'a> = Variant<&'a [u8]>;
```

Here, we end up with two types with "owner-reference" relationship, which is similar to pairs `Vec<T>`-`&[T]`, `String`-`&str`. Docs suggest builtin traits `Borrow` and `ToOwned` which provide just what is required except for a subtle nuance:

```rust
trait Borrow<Borrowed: ?Sized> {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Borrowed;
    // this: -----------^
}

pub trait ToOwned {
    type Owned: Borrow<Self>;
    fn to_owned(&self) -> Self::Owned;
}
```

Result of `borrow` is required to be a *reference to something*, which `BorrowedVariant<'a>` is obviously not. Removing this requirement solves this problem (here, names are prefixed with **alt** to emphasize the fact this is an alternative interface):

```rust
trait AltBorrow<'a, AltBorrowed> {
    fn alt_borrow(&'a self) -> AltBorrowed;
}

trait AltToOwned<'a> {
    type AltOwned: AltBorrow<'a, Self>;
    fn alt_to_owned(&'a self) -> Self::AltOwned;
}
```

This trait could then be implemented for standard types, e.g. `Vec`:

```rust
impl<'a, T> AltBorrow<'a, &'a [T]> for Vec<T> {
    fn alt_borrow(&'a self) -> &'a [T] {
        self.as_slice()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> AltToOwned<'a> for &'a [T]
    where T: Clone
{
    type AltOwned = Vec<T>;

    fn alt_to_owned(&'a self) -> Vec<T> {
        self.to_vec()
    }
}
```

As well as for the `Variant` enum in question:

```rust
impl<'a> AltBorrow<'a, BorrowedVariant<'a>> for OwnedVariant {
    fn alt_borrow(&'a self) -> BorrowedVariant<'a> {
        match self {
            &Variant::Nothing => Variant::Nothing,
            &Variant::SomeInt(value) => Variant::SomeInt(value),
            &Variant::SomeBytes(ref value) => Variant::SomeBytes(value.alt_borrow()),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> AltToOwned<'a> for BorrowedVariant<'a> {
    type AltOwned = OwnedVariant;

    fn alt_to_owned(&'a self) -> OwnedVariant {
        match self {
            &Variant::Nothing => Variant::Nothing,
            &Variant::SomeInt(value) => Variant::SomeInt(value),
            &Variant::SomeBytes(value) => Variant::SomeBytes(value.alt_to_owned()),
        }
    }
}
```

---

Finally, the questions:

1. Am I misusing the original `Borrow`/`ToOwned` concept? Should I use something else to achieve this?
2. If not, then what are the reasons why the current less-generic interface from `std::borrow` might have been preferred?

[This example on Rust playpen](http://is.gd/jzHt4T)

Answer (score 3):

Got [some explanation](https://botbot.me/mozilla/rust/2015-05-06/?msg=38490694&page=39) on #rust IRC.

From **aturon**:

> the short answer is: we'd need higher-kinded types (HKT) to do better here; it should be possible to smoothly "upgrade" to HKT later on, though
>
> (this is a pattern that's come up a few places in the standard library)
>
> (lifting the lifetime to the trait level is a way of encoding HKT, but makes it significantly more awkward to use the trait)

From **bluss**:

> I like your question. That kind of lifetime in a trait hasn't been explored enough IMO
> but it also has a known bug in the borrow checker right now